# How do I make $0 \times (\mathsf{anything})=0$?

Tags: evaluation, hold

I have a complicated formula which is a sum of several terms. Any given term will be a product of factors: $a_1(x)\times a_2(x)\times a_3(x)\times \ldots$, in which for simplicity I have shown that each factor is a function of only one variable $x$. I want to make the convention that if, for some $x=x_0$, even one factor $a_i(x_0)=0$, the whole term becomes zero, irrespective of the value of the other factors in the term (some of which may evaluate to infinity at $x=x_0$).

How do I do that in Mathematica in a general way? For example, one of the terms in my long formula looks like this:

```
(t + s - 1) (t + s)LegendreQ[s-1, t-1, x]LegendreP[s-1, t-1, n]
```

At `t=1 s=0`, `(t + s - 1)=0` but `LegendreQ` evaluates to `ComplexInfinity`, and so the whole expression evaluates to `Indeterminate`, but I want the expression to evaluate to `0`. Of course above is only a sample, and if possible I would like something general enough that can deal with arbitrary expressions.

Comment: @Bill Number of factors in a term is not fixed in my case, so even if your suggestion worked I couldn't use it.

Comment: This breaks math. You really want $x \frac{1}{x}=0$ for $x=0$?

Comment: @VsevolodA. Good point. I worried about that myself. The correct procedure I guess is to evaluate each term in the limit $x\to x_0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Updated solution

@Michael E2 pointed out some issues with the previous solution, so here's another take:

```
expr = (t + s - 1) (t + s) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x] LegendreP[s - 1, t - 1, n]

myTimes[___,0, ___] := 0
myTimes[args___] := Times[args]

expr /. {Times -> myTimes, t -> 1, s -> 0}
(* 0 *)
```

This works by replacing `Times` with `myTimes` before inserting the numerical values. `myTimes` has two properties:

- `myTimes` with a `0` factor is `0`
- `myTimes[args___]` of anything else is the same thing as `Times[args]`

## Old solution

The following should do what you want:

```
expr = (t + s - 1) (t + s) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x] LegendreP[s - 1, t - 1, n]

Activate[
 Inactivate[Evaluate@expr, Times] /.
   {t -> 1, s -> 0} /.
  Inactive[Times][___, 0, ___] :> 0
 ]

(* 0 *)
```

It works like this:

- Apply [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) to all products
- Insert the values for `s` and `t`
- Replace any products containing a `0` factor with `0`
- [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html)the whole expression again

Comment: What do you mean? It correctly returns `ComplexInfinity`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong code. This is one that gives `Indeterminate`: `expr = (t/(s + 1) - 1) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's strange - I can't reproduce that. For me, it returns 0 as it should

Comment: Here's what I did: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qLOvM.png -- Does it look I'm doing the right thing?  The reason (I think) it fails is that `Inactivate[Evaluate@expr, Times] /. {t -> 1, s -> 0}` does not contain an explicit multiplication by `0`, since the factor `(t/(s + 1) - 1)` does not evaluate to `0` until after `Activate`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 good point, not sure why it seems to work for me... I've added an alternative solution that shouldn't have any of these shortcomings

Answer (score 4):

Similar in spirit to Mathe's answer:

```
With[{t = 1, s = 0}, 
 Block[{LegendreQ}, (t + s - 1) (t + s) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x] 
    LegendreP[s - 1, t - 1, n]]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

This is because MMA, in principle, already replaces anything times exact `0` to `0`. When `LegendreQ` is blocked, it doesn't have a chance to evaluate to `ComplexInfinity` so MMA can then apply its usual rules to products with `0`.

By the time the `Block` is released, there is no `LegendreQ` remaining in the expression.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function you can wrap around an expression to inspect if there are any multiplications by 0 inside (and set those multiplications to zero if necessary):

```
SetAttributes[zeroCheck, HoldFirst];
zeroCheck[expr_] := ReplaceAll[
  Unevaluated[expr],
  t_Times :> If[
    AnyTrue[Unevaluated[t], TrueQ[# == 0] &],
    0,
    t
  ]
]
```

We can use it like this to deal with your problem:

```
In[12]:= Module[{
  t = 1,
  s = 0
},
  zeroCheck[(t + s - 1) (t + s) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x] LegendreP[s - 1, t - 1, n]]
]

Out[12]= 0
```

Note, however, that `zeroCheck` is `HoldFirst`, so the following will not work:

```
expr = (t + s - 1) (t + s) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x] LegendreP[s - 1, t - 1, n];
Module[{t = 1, s = 0}, zeroCheck[expr]]
```

Instead, you'd have to do something like this:

```
Clear[expr];
expr[t_, s_] := (t + s - 1) (t + s) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x] LegendreP[s - 1, t - 1, n];
With[{evaluated = expr[t, s]},
 Block[{t = 1, s = 0},
   zeroCheck[evaluated]
 ]
]

0
```

**edit**

I noticed that my definition of `zeroCheck` fails in certain situations (particularly, if fails to propagate zeroes inside of nested `Times` upwards). This new version should avoid this issue:

```
SetAttributes[zeroCheck2, HoldFirst];
zeroCheck2[expr_] :=
 ReleaseHold[
   Hold[expr] //. {
     t_Times /; Quiet[AnyTrue[Unevaluated[t], EqualTo[0]]] :> 0
   }
 ]
```

Compare, e.g., `zeroCheck[\[Infinity]*(0*\[Infinity])]` and `zeroCheck2[\[Infinity]*(0*\[Infinity])]`.

**edit 2**
As pointed out by Michael E2, `zeroCheck2` can produce side effects when testing for equality to zero. We can avert this with the following change:

```
SetAttributes[zeroCheck3, HoldFirst];
zeroCheck3[expr_] := ReleaseHold[
  Hold[expr] //. {
   t_Times /;
      Quiet[
       AnyTrue[
        Unevaluated[t], 
        Function[x, Unevaluated[x] == 0, HoldFirst]
       ]
      ] :> 0
   }
]
```

Comment: I don't know how bullet-proof you want this to be, but `zeroCheck2[{0}*(1/0)]` returns `{Indeterminate}` for me.  So does `foo = -2; zeroCheck2[(++foo)*(1/0)]`; and `++` is evaluated twice (because `EqualTo[0]` evaluates each factor until one is `True`.  So it's not safe on code with side-effects. +1 anyway.

Comment: Good finds to break my code =). Personally I'm not going to worry about those cases too much because they seem quite far removed from what the OP needs. I'll briefly address the side-effects.

Comment: By the way, if you want this to work for every conceivable situation (like multiplication of `List`s etc.), I don't think there's any other way than messing around with the definition of `Times` itself (and any related symbols like `Infinity`). That's probably not a good road walk.

Comment: Yep, I think it's probably impossible, in fact, because of internal rules for `Times` that cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

At first, I thought it would be impossible, except for the simple kind of example of the OP's.  `Inactivate[expr, Times]` only replaces the instances of `Times` literally appearing in `expr`, so its application is limited to cases in which the unevaluated code for `expr` contains all the `Times`, or at least the ones that would lead to `Indeterminate`, that would occur when `expr` is evaluated.  Also, if `expr` already contains `Inactive[Times]`, then this would probably be activated as a side effect, although it could be dealt with.  Overriding `Times` is (1) difficult because there are internal rules that are applied automatically before the normal evaluation sequence, apparently including one for the case at hand, and (2) possibly dangerous to workings of system functions (see below).  Nonetheless, I present a function `zerofy` that overrides `Times` that seems to work for symbolic calculation.  The only way (I think) you can do it is by replacing the head `Times` when the head is evaluated, so that the internal rules are never invoked.  This can be done with `Block`.  I haven't tried this with numerical functions like `Plot`, `FindRoot`, etc.  I doubt it would work, or even could be made to work.

Notes on the code: The indirection `Hold[times]... /. Hold[times] -> times` prevents infinite recursion (from the second rule for `times[]`).  One could add rules for `0.` and ``` 0.``acc ``` as desired.

```
ClearAll[zerofy];
SetAttributes[zerofy, HoldFirst];
zerofy[expr_] := Module[{times},
  SetAttributes[times,   (* some attributes of Times *)
   {Flat, Listable, OneIdentity, Orderless}]; 
  times[0, ___] := 0;    (* Orderless => matches a 0 anywhere *)
  times[args___] := Times[args];
  Block[{Times = Hold[times]}, expr] /. Hold[times] -> times
  ]

expr = (t + s - 1) (t + s) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x] LegendreP[s - 1, t - 1, n];
zerofy[expr /. {t -> 1, s -> 0}]
(*  0  *)

expr = (t/(s + 1) - 1) LegendreQ[s - 1, t - 1, x];
zerofy[expr /. {t -> 1, s -> 0}]
(*  0  *)

zerofy[{0, 1}/0]
```

> TimeConstrained::timc: Number of seconds 1.` is not a positive machine-sized number or Infinity.
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

```
(*  {0, ComplexInfinity}  *)
```

Despite the messages, the answer is what was desired.  The bizarre `TimeConstrained` error is one of those things that happens when you mess with core functions like `Times`, I guess:

```
Block[{Times = "h"}, Power[0, -1]]
```

> TimeConstrained::timc: Number of seconds 1.` is not a positive machine-sized number or Infinity.
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

```
(*  ComplexInfinity  *)
```

The `TimeConstrained` error could be avoided by using `Inactivate[expr, Times]` and replacing `Inactive[Times]` by `times`; however, if `expr` already contains `Inactive[Times]`, then these would be activated as a side effect.

Comment: I was toying in my head with a method like this and couldn't figure out how to make it work. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate) approach:

```
inactivateReplacement[expr_, rules_] := Activate @ ReplaceAll[
    Inactivate[expr, Except[Times|Plus|Power]],
    rules
]
```

For your example:

```
inactivateReplacement[
    (t+s-1) (t+s) LegendreQ[s-1, t-1, x] LegendreP[s-1, t-1, n],
    {t->1, s->0}
]
```

> 0